# Sideways figures only are 50 % on the page

Tags: rotating, landscape

I am using the Springer Monography class and am trying to include sideway graphics. What always happens is that with rotating the Graphs end up about 50 % to the right of the page. They were fine on landscape, but on landscape the text doesn't float. On Sideways the text floats fine, but now the graphs don't show.

See attached screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}

%\begin{landscape}
%\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{C:/Dropbox/Publication/Graphs/CreditMatrix-bw.png}
    \caption{Best practices for organization of credit management}
    \label{fig:CreditMatrix}
    \caption*{Own Diagram}
%\end{figure}
%\end{landscape}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\documentclass[12pt]{svmono1}
% [graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]
% choose options for [] as required from the list
% in the Reference Guide

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
%
\usepackage{type1cm} 
% Mein Teil

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{rotating}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Are sure you don't have white space on the top of your image (try and crop it a bit and see the effect).

Comment: Could be related to this problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136379/wrong-position-on-separate-page-of-sideways-figures-in-amsart