# sidewaystable doesn't fit on page

Tags: tables, floats, rotating

I have the problem, that my sidewaystable doesn't fit on the page. It is moved to the left. Can anyone help me?
Here is a minimal example of what my table looks like in my document

```
\documentclass[german,11pt,twoside,a4paper,final,titlepage,openany]{amsbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy,amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[!htb]
\caption{Tabelle}\label{tab:Tabelle}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|ccccccccccccc|}
\hline
 -20 & -10 & 0& 10 &20 & 30 & 40 & 50 &60 &70 &80&90& 100\\\hline

-15,20  &   -15,20  &   -15,20  &   -15,10  &   -15,10  &-15,20 &   -15,20  &   -15,10  &    -15,30 &   -15,10  &   -16,10  &-16,00 &   -15,90  \\
-10,30  &   -10,30  &   -10,10  &   -10,30  &   -10,30  &   -10,20  &   -10,40  &   -10,40  &    -10,20 &   -10,50  &   -11,10  &   -11,10  &   -11,30  \\
-9,30   &   -9,40   &   -9,40   &   -9,40   &   -9,70   &   -9,40   &   -9,30   &   -9,70   &    -9,50  &   -9,30   &   -9,20   &   -9,20   &   -9,30   \\
-6,10   &   -7,00   &   -7,20   &   -6,90   &   -7,00   &   -6,90   &   -6,70   &   -6,80   &    -6,80  &   -6,90   &   -7,50   &   -7,50   &   -7,30   \\
-3,60   &   -5,30   &   -5,20   &   -5,10   &   -5,00   &   -5,00   &   -5,00   &   -5,00   &    -5,20  &   -5,00   &   -5,90   &   -5,50   &   -5,70   \\
-1,40   &   -3,20   &   -3,40   &   -3,20   &   -3,20   &   -3,20   &   -2,90   &   -2,90   &    -3,10  &   -3,30   &   -3,70   &   -3,70   &   -3,70   \\
0,80    &   -1,00   &   -0,90   &   -0,90   &   -0,90   &   -0,80   &   -0,70   &   -0,90   &    -0,80  &   -1,00   &   -1,80   &   -1,30   &   -1,40   \\
0,30    &   0,30    &   0,40    &   0,40    &   -0,20   &   0,40    &   0,50    &   0,00    &    0,20   &   0,50    &   0,90    &   0,80    &   0,90    \\
3,50    &   1,30    &   1,70    &   1,60    &   1,50    &   1,60    &   1,60    &   1,60    &    1,70   &   1,50    &   0,90    &   1,00    &   1,00    \\
6,50    &   4,10    &   4,30    &   4,30    &   4,40    &   4,60    &   4,30    &   4,20    &    4,30   &   4,40    &   3,80    &   3,80    &   3,80    \\
10,10   &   7,50    &   7,60    &   7,50    &   7,70    &   7,80    &   7,60    &   7,50    &    7,50   &   7,40    &   7,20    &   6,90    &   7,30    \\
9,20    &   9,50    &   9,60    &   9,50    &   8,70    &   9,50    &   9,70    &   9,40    &    9,30   &   9,90    &   10,30   &   9,90    &   10,30   \\
15,20   &   11,70   &   11,70   &   11,70   &   11,80   &   11,60   &   11,80   &   11,70   &    11,60  &   11,40   &   11,30   &   11,50   &   11,30   \\
23,00   &   17,30   &   17,40   &   17,30   &   17,30   &   17,40   &   17,40   &   17,40   &    17,30  &   17,30   &   17,20   &   17,00   &   16,90   \\
17,50   &   17,70   &   18,00   &   17,50   &   17,30   &   17,70   &   17,90   &   17,70   &    17,60  &   18,40   &   17,90   &   17,90   &   18,30   \\
24,90   &   25,00   &   25,40   &   24,90   &   24,80   &   25,00   &   25,30   &   25,20   &    25,30  &   25,60   &   24,90   &   24,90   &   25,20   \\
38,80   &   27,80   &   27,80   &   28,30   &   27,80   &   27,60   &   27,60   &   27,70   &    27,70  &   27,70   &   27,80   &   27,40   &   27,70   \\
30,80   &   30,80   &   31,30   &   30,70   &   30,90   &   31,20   &   31,00   &   31,10   &    31,00  &   31,50   &   29,90   &   29,80   &   29,80   \\
31,10   &   31,20   &   31,50   &   31,40   &   31,90   &   31,70   &   31,60   &   31,50   &    31,50  &   31,60   &   30,00   &   29,70   &   30,10   \\
33,00   &   33,10   &   33,20   &   32,90   &   32,30   &   32,60   &   32,70   &   32,70   &    32,90  &   33,30   &   33,50   &   33,30   &   33,60   \\
37,40   &   37,50   &   37,50   &   37,00   &   36,60   &   37,00   &   37,20   &   37,30   &    37,20  &   37,60   &   36,90   &   36,90   &   36,80   \\
37,80   &   37,90   &   38,10   &   38,20   &   38,70   &   38,50   &   38,60   &   38,30   &    38,50  &   38,20   &   36,20   &   36,20   &   36,30   \\
38,00   &   38,00   &   38,20   &   38,00   &   38,20   &   38,40   &   38,10   &   38,20   &    38,10  &   38,20   &   37,10   &   36,90   &   37,40   \\
41,90   &   41,90   &   42,10   &   42,10   &   41,90   &       41,90   &   41,80   &   41,90   &    41,90  &   42,10   &   41,70   &   41,80   &   41,90   \\
\end{tabular}\label{table:data}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for any suggestions! Nina

Comment: Looks like it's the same problem solved in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136379/wrong-position-on-separate-page-of-sideways-figures-in-amsart/136383#136383

Comment: Great, thanks for your help, wouldn't have found that thread on my own :-)