# Landscape table will not be in centre of page

Tags: tables, landscape

I read all the questions and answers on this, but they only left me more confused. I want my table to be in the centre of the landscape page, but it's always aligned on the left instead. Is there a way to make it appear in the centre? I am including the packages and commands from the preamble of my document in case they are causing clashes. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{relsize, fullpage, url, amsmath, amssymb, graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape, afterpage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}
Some text

\afterpage{

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h] %[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|cccccccccccccccccccccc}
& 0& 1 &2& 3&4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18& 19& 20 &21\\
& 0& 1 &2& 3&4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18& 19& 20 &21\\
& 0& 1 &2& 3&4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18& 19& 20 &21\\
& 0& 1 &2& 3&4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18& 19& 20 &21\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{I want this table to be in the middle of the page, above the 2. It would also be nice if there was more vertical space before this caption.}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By replacing `amsart` with `article` and `lscape` with `rotating` (and using a `sidewaystable` instead of a `landscape` and `table`), I get a table centered on the page. Are you required to use `amsart` and `lscape`?

Comment: Yes, I know that article is OK. It was changing it to amsart which caused the problem.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136383/3345) of [Wrong position (on separate page) of sideways figures in amsart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136379/) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a pair of `\vfill` inside the `landscape` environment. I added `threeparttable`, in order not to have the table caption much wider than the table, and gave some more spacing between table and caption:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{relsize, fullpage, url, amsmath, amssymb, graphicx, array}
\usepackage{lscape, afterpage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
Some text

\afterpage{

\begin{landscape}
\mbox{}\vfill
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l|*{22}{c}}
& 0& 1 &2& 3&4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18& 19& 20 &21\\
& 0& 1 &2& 3&4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18& 19& 20 &21\\
& 0& 1 &2& 3&4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18& 19& 20 &21\\
& 0& 1 &2& 3&4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17& 18& 19& 20 &21\\
\end{tabular}
\vskip 2ex
\caption{I want this table to be in the middle of the page, above the 2. It would also be nice if there was more vertical space before this caption.}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\vfill
\end{landscape}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly!